# Calculate number of bytes to fetch , Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, fetch, disassembly

I'm tying to calculate how much byte the "fetch" need.

I'm writing in assembly this code

```
jmp [2*eax]
```

and the command in the list file is 3 bytes.

when i'm writing this command :

```
jmp [4*eax]
```

I got 7 bytes

does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your assembler is being smart and is encoding the `jmp [2*eax]` as `jmp [eax+eax]` which takes fewer bytes since it doesn't require a displacement. Whereas `jmp [4*eax]` is really the equivalent of `jmp [4*eax+0x00000000]` which requires an extra 4 bytes for the displacement.

It has to do with the was the SIB (scaled index byte) works. Typically this encodes addresses in the form `base + index*scale + displacement`. The *displacement* is optional, but only if a *base* register is included. If you want to leave off the *base* register, then you are forced to include a 32 bit *displacement*.

So to get `eax*4` you need to use the form `index*4 + displacement` even though you don't need that *displacement*. But to get eax*2, you can use the form `base + index*scale` (i.e. `eax+eax*1`), and avoid having to include the *displacement*.